# Why does window.addEventListener exist?

Tags: events, window, w3c

DOM4 says [`EventTarget`](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-eventtarget) has a `addEventListener` method and [`Node`](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#node) inherits from `EventTarget`.

Now [`Document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-document) inherits from `Node` so it makes sense that `document.addEventListener` works.

However `Window` is not a `Node`. Why does the window method allow you to attach event listeners?

Of course [`Window`](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/) says nothing about `EventTarget` or `.addEventListener`

*Aside:* Why do I care? Whilst writing the [DOM-shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim) my attempts to emulate `window.addEventListener` get crushed because `window.fireEvent` doesn't exist in IE8. I'd be nice to not have to support `window.addEventListener`

*Further Aside:* If `window.addEventListener` is non-standard should we try to get rid of it and replace it with `document.addEventListener` ? Should we file bugs with browser vendors?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bug" here...

Comment: @BoltClock bug as in, this method is not defined anywhere on the specification, is it a bug that it exists. Phrasing is bad, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to HTML5, Window is not a Node, but it is an EventTarget. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/browsers.html#the-window-object

Comment: Ugh why doesn't anyone mention the Window spec is not where I'm supposed to be looking but I should look at the HTML5 spec instead.